# Dereferencing a pointer as for-loop condition?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was under the impression a for loop has to consist of: `for(init; condition; increment)`
Now I came across this code:

```
char *foo, *bar;
char* data = getData();

for (foo = data; *foo; foo = bar + 1) {
        for (bar = foo; *bar; ++bar) {
         if (bar >= &data[1024]) { 
           printf("error\n");           
         }
        printf("%s\n", foo);
}
```

Is the dereferencing of a pointer a valid condition? If so, when does it return `false`? When it points to NULL?

Comment: Any condition is valid and as long as it is not 0(aka NULL) then it is true...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the dereferencing of a pointer a valid condition?

In C and C++, any expression that can be converted to a `bool` in a given context can be used as a valid condition in a loop or a conditional statement. An expression `*foo` produces a value of type `char`, which is convertible to `bool`.

> when does it return false?

When the expression evaluates to zero. All other values are considered `true`.

> When it points to `NULL`?

`foo` is a `char*`, so the condition becomes `false` when `*foo` is `'\0'`

Comment: That makes sense, since the Data consists of `NUL` terminated character sequences...

Comment: Not *any* non-void expression; it has to be contextually convertible to `bool`.