# Is pointer valid condition for a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

**Can someone carefully explain, why in this case for loop repeats 10 times?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    int length=-1;
    char s[]="Bad or nice";//10 characters 

    for ( char *q = s; *q; ++q ){
    cout << *q;
    length++;
    }

    cout << "\n" << length;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: **VERY IMPORTANT:**  The condition is not comparing the value of the pointer, but the variable it is pointing to.  Research *pointer* and *dereferencing pointers*.

Comment: Possible of duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761235/dereferencing-a-pointer-as-for-loop-condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is the value at the memory location of the pointer (`*q`).

Therefore the loop terminates when the `NULL` character is reached (at the end of the string), which is evaluated as false.

Comment: So *q conditions says "The loop ends, while NULL is reached", yes?

Comment: So it could be written for (*q=s; *q!='\0'; ++q) , yes?

Comment: Would be better to say the `*q` condition means the loop runs until the `NULL` character is reached.

Comment: Yes, using `*q!='\0'` in the condition would also be valid and perhaps make more sense to others reading your code.

Answer (score 4):

Total characters in the string is `11` excluding `\0`. Second `for` expression `*q` becomes `false` when `q` points to last character of the string `s`, which is `\0`.
Therefore, loop repeats `11` times. You are getting `10` output because you initialized `length` with `-1`.

Comment: Ok even If i set length=0; I still do not understand why It repeats 11 times.